# Mixpanel - Bulk delete old users

Tags: mixpanel

I am about to go into the next plan in mixpanel for having too many people and would like to delete some old users first.

Is there a simple way/script/api to bulk delete old users?

Answer (score 10):

I've written two scripts that may come in handy; [mixpanel-engage-query](https://github.com/stpe/mixpanel-engage-query) and [mixpanel-engage-post](https://github.com/stpe/mixpanel-engage-post).

Using the first script (query) you can query your People Data and get a list of profiles, e.g. all users who have $last_seen set to a date older than X months.

Using the second script (post) you can perform actions in batch on those profiles, for example deleting them. See the README for [an example of how to perform a batch delete](https://github.com/stpe/mixpanel-engage-post#batch-delete-people-profiles).

Answer (score 8):

Yes there is. Looking at the [HTTP spec](https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/http) you'll find the following.

> **$delete**
>
> string Permanently delete the profile from Mixpanel, along with all of
>   its properties. The value is ignored - the profile is determined by
>   the $distinct_id from the request itself.

```
// This removes the user 13793 from Mixpanel
{
    "$token": "36ada5b10da39a1347559321baf13063",
    "$distinct_id": "13793",
    "$delete": ""
}
```

**Batch requests**

Both the events endpoint at http://api.mixpanel.com/track/ and the profile update endpoint at http://api.mixpanel.com/engage/ accept batched updates. To send a batch of messages to an endpoint, you should use a POST instead of a GET request. Instead of sending a single JSON object as the data query parameter, send a JSON list of objects, base64 encoded, as the data parameter of an application/x-www-form-urlencoded POST request body.

```
// Here's a list of events
[
    {
        "event": "Signed Up",
        "properties": {
            "distinct_id": "13793",
            "token": "e3bc4100330c35722740fb8c6f5abddc",
            "Referred By": "Friend",
            "time": 1371002000
        }
    },
    {
         "event": "Uploaded Photo",
          "properties": {
              "distinct_id": "13793",
              "token": "e3bc4100330c35722740fb8c6f5abddc",
              "Topic": "Vacation",
              "time": 1371002104
          }
    }
]
```

Base64 encoded, the list becomes:

```
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
```

So the body of a POST request to send the events as a batch is:

```
data=Ww0KICAgIHsNCiAgICAgICAgImV2ZW50IjogIlNpZ25lZCBVcCIsDQogICAgICAgICJwcm9wZXJ0aWVzIjogew0KICAgICAgICAgICAgImRpc3RpbmN0X2lkIjogIjEzNzkzIiwNCiAgICAgICAgICAgICJ0b2tlbiI6ICJlM2JjNDEwMDMzMGMzNTcyMjc0MGZiOGM2ZjVhYmRkYyIsDQogICAgICAgICAgICAiUmVmZXJyZWQgQnkiOiAiRnJpZW5kIiwNCiAgICAgICAgICAgICJ0aW1lIjogMTM3MTAwMjAwMA0KICAgICAgICB9DQogICAgfSwNCiAgICB7DQogICAgICAgICAiZXZlbnQiOiAiVXBsb2FkZWQgUGhvdG8iLA0KICAgICAgICAgICJwcm9wZXJ0aWVzIjogew0KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAiZGlzdGluY3RfaWQiOiAiMTM3OTMiLA0KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAidG9rZW4iOiAiZTNiYzQxMDAzMzBjMzU3MjI3NDBmYjhjNmY1YWJkZGMiLA0KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAiVG9waWMiOiAiVmFjYXRpb24iLA0KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAidGltZSI6IDEzNzEwMDIxMDQNCiAgICAgICAgICB9DQogICAgfQ0KXQ==
```

Both endpoints will accept up to 50 messages in a single batch. Usually, batch requests will have a "time" property associated with events, or a "$time" attribute associated with profile updates.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Mixpanel-api python Module](https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel_api)

```
pip install mixpanel-api
```

This script will delete any profile that hasn't been seen since January 1st, 2019:

```
from mixpanel_api import Mixpanel

mixpanel = Mixpanel('MIXPANEL_SECRET', token='MIXPANEL_TOKEN')

deleted_count = mixpanel.people_delete(query_params={ 'selector' : 'user["$last_seen"]<"2019-01-01T00:00:00"'})
print(deleted_count)
```

Replace **MIXPANEL_SECRET** and **MIXPANEL_TOKEN** with your own project tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Install Mixpanel Python API ([Click Here](https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel_api))

```
pip install mixpanel-api
```

Create a python file : delete_people.py and copy and paste below code and perform changes as per your project configuration, i.e secret,token, filter params etc.

```
from mixpanel_api import Mixpanel
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
current_time = now.strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Mixpanel Project :     
    credentials = {
    'API_secret': '<Your API Secret>',
    'token': '<Your API Token>',
    }
    # first we are going to make a Mixpanel object instance
    mlive = Mixpanel(credentials['API_secret'])

    # Mixpanel object with token to delete people
    ilive = Mixpanel(credentials['API_secret'],credentials['token'])

    #Prepare parameters for delete condition
    #<filter_by_cohort_here> - Get from mixpanel explore UI, from engage api xhr call (https://mixpanel.com/api/2.0/engage)
    parameters = {'filter_by_cohort':'<filter_by_cohort_here>','include_all_users':'true','limit':0}

    # Backup data before deleting
    print("\n Creating backup of data\n")
    mlive.export_people('backup_people_'+current_time+'.json', parameters)

    # Delete people using parameters filter
    print("\n Backup Completed! Deleting Data\n")
    ilive.people_delete(query_params=parameters)

    print("\n Data Deleted Successfully\n")
```

Run below command from terminal

```
python delete_people.py
```

*Note: people_delete method of mixpanel api will automatically create backup_timestamp.json file in same directory where you put this script*